# How to set third level domain for GitHub project page

Tags: github, github-pages

I have set a custom domain for my personal GitHub page and all my projects GitHub pages are like,

```
mydomin.com # <- My GitHub Account Page
mydomin.com/project1 # <- Project 1 gh-pages
mydomin.com/project2 # <- Project 2 gh-pages
```

Is there a way to make the domain name for my project GitHub page using 3rd level domain `project1.mydomin.com` instead of `mydomin.com/project1`.

I tried to set up using `CNAME` but *cloudflare* seems does not allow me to set `username.github.io/project1` as an alias. When I using `@project1` to represent the root domain, which make the link into `mydomin.comproject1`. All other combinations are invalid hostname.

Thanks for your time viewing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is the following,

1. Set the DNS (See image below, Cloudflare is the server I choosen), the value should be your account GitHub page `username.github.io`.

[image]

2. Create a `CNAME` file which contains the 3rd level domain. For example, `bus.li-xinyang.com`

And that's it. Now you can name the whatever the project name you like without worrying the gh-pages url.